# Where do the electrons that are filled up to the fermi level above the valence band go?

Tags: energy, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

Many questions have been asked on this topic, but this has never been answered satisfactorily. Yet I want to give it a shot. Fermi Energy represents the energy level achieved when all the available electrons are filled in the possible energy states at 0 Kelvin. But since there are no states above the valence band maxima, where do the electrons that still need to be assigned a state go? How are they fitted into the energy states till the valence band maxima?

Comment: Where is the Fermi energy at 0K?

Comment: I'm confused by this question. If one band is filled and there are left over electrons, then they go into the next band.  Why are you saying that there are no states above the valence band maximum, when there is another band above the valence band?

Comment: We define fermi energy as the maximum level of electron occupancy. But the valence band is below it. For a semiconductor, we say the valence band is completely filled and the conduction band is empty at 0 K. On one hand we say electrons are occupied upto fermi level, and on the other hand we say it is only upto valence band maxima. Thats why I am confused.

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. Start with: Fermi energy is the highest energy of occupied states. Take all electrons, fill up the states from bottom to top (energy wise). If the valence band is full, and you have left over electrons, fill up the next band. Then you say: a semiconductor has a full valence band and an empty conduction band at T=0K. Then by the definition, the Fermi energy is at the VB edge. If you have a metal, i.e. there are leftover electrons when the VB is full, you fill up parts of the CB, then the Fermi energy lies somewhere in the CB.

Answer (score 0):

The Fermi Energy is the name given to the highest energy occupied electron orbital at absolute zero. The band structure of an insulator is shown below, with the Fermi energy sitting between the two bands.

[image: Band structure metal, semiconductor, insulator]

There are additional localised electronic states within the bandgap (at higher energies than the valence band). These states arise from defects in the crystal structure of the material, and do not contribute to conduction since the electrons cannot move. The occupation of these localised states (at $0$K) sets the position of the Fermi level.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more electrons than can fit in the valence band, they go into the conduction band, and you have a conductor.

Comment: This is not correct. The poster was asking about the level of the Fermi energy. In this case it is set by electrons in localised states, which arise due to defects in the lattice structure of the crystal.